# geoPy error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'

Tags: python, xml, geolocation, geocoding, geopy

i have and xml with a list of addresses and I'm trying to iterate through them and extract information (i.e: lat, lon, distances etc..) using geopy, but i keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'.
Heres the code, if anyone has any idea:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import urllib, json
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
root = et.parse('data.xml').getroot()

for child in root:
    adress = child.find('adress').text + ' beer sheva'
    location = geolocator.geocode(adress)
    print location.address # i'm trying to acces some information here.
```

and for a sample of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ShelterInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Shelter>
        <adress>אחד העם 21</adress>
        <code>1 - א</code>
        <neighborhood>א</neighborhood>
    </Shelter>
    <Shelter>
        <adress>13 שלח</adress>
        <code>10 - א</code>
        <neighborhood>א</neighborhood>
    </Shelter>
    <Shelter>
        <adress>ביאליק</adress>
        <code>11 - א</code>
        <neighborhood>א</neighborhood>
    </Shelter>
```

as you can tell the addresses are in hebrew but it shouldnt pose a problem. for the first address everything works well, but then i get the error. I'm guesing it has something to do with the way I iterate over the xml file, any ideas?

Much obliged!

Comment: Clearly `geolocator.geocode(...)` is returning `None`. Have you looked at [the docs](http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.1.0/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode), or [the source](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/1.1.0/geopy/geocoders/osm.py)? Checked what `adress` actually is?

Comment: adress is a string with an address(just mispelled ;)) so it should run as a query on that address.

Comment: I mean, have you tried `print adress`? Does it look how you expect? Have you tried to run `geolocator.geocode` on the same value as a literal string? Do you get a response then?

Comment: oh yeah i forgor to mension, yes i have, if i literally write each and every one of the addresses as a string it works fine, but if i run them in that for loop something goes terribly wrong. thats why my instinct is something goes wrong inside the loop - maybe with instantiaion? but is should work fine, its just a string. same with just 'print adress'

Comment: okay so i ran it through the dataset again and i think theres something wrong with the address itself.

Comment: Could you please pin this down a bit more to the precise issue - is it the XML, the data, the geocoder, ...? See e.g. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: No, i found the issue it was a misspelle of the address itself. but now it seems to run into a 'geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out' error after a couple of addresses. any clues? (i have like 262 addresses)

Answer (score 1):

First I would use these to handle your TimedOut error as well as instead of Nominatim.

```
from geopy import geocoders
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
```

Also sign up for an [API key with Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com).
It limits you to 2,500 inquiries a day but that shouldn't be an issue for your 262 address. Once you've done that you can geocode very simply with the following.

```
g = geocoders.GoogleV3(api_key='yourApiKeyHere')
location = g.geocode(address, timeout=10)
print(location.address)
```

or you can also view the longitude and latitude independently.

```
print(location.longitude, location.latitude)
```

this version handles incorrect data much better than Nomatims but you should still put everything into a few try/except blocks to make sure. So your final code should look something like this.

```
g = geocoders.GoogleV3(api_key='yourApiKeyHere')
try:
    location = g.geocode(address, timeout=10)
    print(location.address)
except AttributeError:
    print("Problem with data or cannot Geocode."
except GeocoderTimedOut:
    # possibly use recursion to have it run until it no longer runs into a timeout error
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!